# get the id of the row with the least value, group by an other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I ran into a problem trying to pull one action per user with the least priority, the priority is based on other columns content and is an integer,

This is the initial query :

```
SELECT
    CASE
       ...
    END AS dummy_priority,
    id,
    user_id
FROM
    actions
```

**Result :**

```
id  user_id     priority
1   2345        1
2   2345        3
3   2999        5
4   2999        2
5   3000        10
```

**Desired result :**

```
id  user_id     priority
1   2345        1
4   2999        2
5   3000        10
```

Following what i want i tried

```
SELECT x.id, x.user_id, MIN(x.priority)
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE
             ...
        END AS priority,
        id,
        user_id
    FROM
        actions
) x
GROUP BY x.user_id
```

Which didn't work

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
>   clause and contains nonaggregated column 'x.id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;

Most examples of this I found were extracting just the user_id and priority and then doing an inner join with both of them to get the row, but I can't do that since (priority, user_id) isn't unique

A simple verifiable example would be

```
CREATE TABLE `actions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `actions` (`id`, `user_id`, `priority`) VALUES
(1, 2345, 1),
(2, 2345, 3),
(3, 2999, 5),
(4, 2999, 2),
(5, 3000, 10);
```

how to extract the desired result (please hold in mind that this table is a subquery)?

Comment: Like trying to sell a stick without a lollipop

Comment: what do you mean? is it the lack of information?

Comment: Yes. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you, it is logical to want an example, i added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this would involve a subquery of some sort . . . and that would require repeating the `case` definition.

Here is another method, using the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(x.id ORDER BY x.priority), ',', 1) as id,
       x.user_id, MIN(x.priority)
FROM (SELECT (CASE ...
              END) AS priority,
             id, user_id
      FROM actions a
     ) x
GROUP BY x.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

And that proper way in full...

```
SELECT x...
     , CASE...x... priority 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , MIN(CASE...) priority 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) y 
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
   AND y.priority = CASE...x...;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work ...

```
SELECT id , user_id, priority FROM actions act
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT
        user_id, MIN(priority) AS priority 
    FROM
        actions
GROUP BY user_id) pri
ON act.user_id = pri.user_id AND act.priority = pri.prority
```